# First uses of the term "crackpottery" in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

I first stumbled over the term [crackpottery](http://www.goodmath.org/blog/2013/03/21/genius-continuum-crackpottery/) on MO and as I am not a native English speaker, I had first assumed that the meaning were *pots for making crack*, i.e. the drug of the name crack.

> **Question:**
>
> can the first uses of the term "crackpottery" in the context of math papers be traced back to a specific mathematician and/or location or event?

Underwood Dudley apparently coined/popularized the term Trisectors for mathematical cranks in 1983 in the March issue of the Mathematical Intelligencer, by asking "*What to do when the Trisector comes?*".
So is it customary to use the term "Trisectors" for the cranks and "crackpottery" for their works?

I would also appreciate answers with little stories about when you first heard the term "crackpottery" being used in a talk or lecture.

If this question is felt to be off topic, please vote to close it.

Comment: I rather like this question, but yeah, it seems pretty far off topic.

Comment: "Pot" is an old colloquialism for "head", so a "crackpot" is someone with a cracked head. There are plenty of examples from the 1800s.  An older version, going back at least to the 16th century, is "crackbrain". None of this answers the mathematical question.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay that explanations further clarifies that it doesn't relate to pottery in a literal meaning. Thanks for elucidating that to the non native English speakers.

Comment: Not sure if it counts as a "math paper", but Paul Halmos mentioned crackpot inventors and crank experiments in his 1958 piece "Innovation in mathematics" in Scientific American.

Comment: (But to clarify: Halmos not really referring to crackpottery *in math*, rather in engineering and physics.)

Comment: Augustus de Morgan's 1872 book "A Budget of Paradoxes" refers to a persistent circle-squarer as a "crack man". I haven't heard that variation before.

Comment: @ManfredWeis The term exists quite literally in the same meaning also in (very colloquial!) German language -- *einen Sprung in der Schüssel haben*.

Comment: @StefanKohl that's true, but I can't think up a nice translation of crackpottery to German that uses the same "image" of a cracked pot as a noun that could be used for cranky maths in German.

Comment: I think the question belongs in https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crackpot) says that *crackpot* was originally *crack-pate* and *pate* is definitely an archaic word for *head*.

Comment: There's some interesting historical information [here](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Squaring_the_circle/) about the related term "circle-squarer" which apparently goes back to ancient times.